# MySQL count(DISTINCT) very slow - better with subqueries?

Tags: mysql, select, count, subquery, distinct

I have one flat table, with about 10mio rows, each row has 15 columns.
Index are set to column_1, column_2, column_3 and my_time.

```
  SELECT    Date(my_time) my_time, 
            count(DISTINCT column_1) c_c1, 
            count(DISTINCT column_2) c_c2 
    FROM    `table_name` 
   WHERE    `column_3` in (10,11,100,50,213,756) 
     AND    Date(my_time) > '2016-09-01' 
     AND    Date(my_time) < '2016-09-30' 
GROUP BY    Date(my_time) 
ORDER BY    Date(my_time) ASC
```

Results took about 20-30 seconds.

Does anybody know, how to improve this query, maybe with subqueries?
In case of subquery, can you show me an example query, how to increase the performance?

thanks!

Comment: Do an [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) and post that in your answer.

Comment: Try changing to my_time BETWEEN '2016-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-09-30 23:59:59'

Comment: id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: table_name
type: ALL
possible_keys: my_time,column_3
key: NULL
key_len: NULL
ref: NULL
rows: ....
Extra: Using where; Using filesort

Answer (score 2):

You can probably speed this up with an appropriate index:

```
create index idx_speedy on table_name(column_3, my_time);
```

Or better even a covering index:

```
create index idx_speedy on table_name(column_3, my_time, column_1, column_2);
```

In order to make better use of the index, try to avoid functions on the columns in your where clause, i.e. avoid `Date(my_time)` there.

```
  SELECT    Date(my_time) my_time, 
            COUNT(DISTINCT column_1) AS c_c1, 
            COUNT(DISTINCT column_2) AS c_c2 
    FROM    table_name
   WHERE    column_3 in (10, 11, 100, 50, 213, 756) 
     AND    my_time >= '2016-09-02' 
     AND    my_time < '2016-09-30' 
GROUP BY    Date(my_time) 
ORDER BY    Date(my_time) ASC;
```

Comment: This should speed up the query quite a bit. But I think you should also have a separate `INDEX my_time` to speed up the `ORDER BY` clause

Comment: Unfortunately no improvement.

Explain shows me now: 

id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: table_name
type: index
possible_keys: my_time, column_3, speed_idx
key: speed_idx
key_len: 173
ref: NULL
rows: ....
Extra: Using where, Using index, Using filesort

Comment: Too bad, I think this is as fast as it gets with the table given. @jussius: No, that won't help; the sorting is not done on `my_time`, but on `Date(my_time)`, and anyway `my_time` is already in my index.

Answer (score 0):

If MySQL supported function indexes we could stick to `Date(my_time)` and create this index for your query:

```
create index idx_speedy on table_name(column_3, Date(my_time), column_1, column_2);
```

As MySQL doesn't support this, you could decide to create a **generated column** instead:

```
alter table table_name add my_date date generated always as ( Date(my_time) );
```

create the index

```
create index idx_speedy on table_name(column_3, my_date, column_1, column_2);
```

and re-write your query accordingly:

```
  SELECT    my_date, 
            COUNT(DISTINCT column_1) AS c_c1, 
            COUNT(DISTINCT column_2) AS c_c2 
    FROM    table_name 
   WHERE    column_3 in (10, 11, 100, 50, 213, 756) 
     AND    my_date BETWEEN '2016-09-02' AND '2016-09-29' 
GROUP BY    my_date 
ORDER BY    my_date ASC;
```

This is available as of MySQL 5.7.6 if I am not mistaken.